# New commits to github aren't getting accepted.

Tags: git, github

I've written an online food ordering system and I've uploaded the code into github. Check this [link](https://github.com/akulkarni9/miniNet).
When I attempt for new commits from my terminal, it returns the following errors.

```
Username for 'https://github.com': akulkarni9
Password for 'https://akulkarni9@github.com': 
To https://github.com/akulkarni9/miniNet.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/akulkarni9/miniNet.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I've used the following commands for new commits:
`git commit -m "second commit"`
`git add --all`
`git push -u origin master`
And I get the above error when those 3 commands are executed. How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to do a `git pull` first.

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you need to pull the changes that happened at the remote.

Comment: And I suppose you mean to first `add`, then `commit`. Otherwise your `commit -m` does not commit anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you need to add *before* `git commit`.

Since you have local commits that you haven't pushed yet, it would be better to do a `git pull --rebase` (in order to replay your local commits on top of the updated `origin/master` branch)

And if the `git pull` fails because local changes might be overridden, you need to stash:

```
git stash
git pull --rebase
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 2):

[All of the commits on that repository](https://github.com/akulkarni9/miniNet/commits/master) are by one single person, presumably yourself. The other answers here take into account the possibility that someone else pushed commits to your repository, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

If you managed to get this on your own, then you probably used `git commit --amend`, `git rebase`, `git reset` or similar to discard old commits from your local repository. In that case, you almost certainly *want* to remove them from your remote repository as well, and the command for that is simple: just add the `--force` option to `git push`.